# How to set up a subclass of UIScrollView, and connect it in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

First of all I began with the code below in my view controller but for reasons that work for me I needed the below code to be in a separate class. So I created a CustomView class which I've posted below.

At this point is it possible for me to create an instance of this class in my view controller, create an IBOutlet and connect it to a UIScrollView (or some kind of view) in interface builder and get the same kind of behavior, and how would I do something like that?

customView.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface CustomView : UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate> {

    UIScrollView    *scrollView;
    UIImageView     *imageView;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView     *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView               *imageView;
```

customView.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@implementation CustomView
@synthesize scrollView, imageView;


    - (id)init {

        if (self = [super init]) {

            // Initialization code
            UIImageView *temp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
            self.imageView = temp;
            [temp release];

            scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);
            //Other Scroll View Properties
            scrollView.delegate = self;
            [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
        }

        return self;
    }


    - (void)dealloc {
        [scrollView release];
        [imageView release];
        [super dealloc];
    }


    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

        //Perform an action

    }

    @end
```

Comment: What's up with the second UIScrollView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an instance of `CustomView` in IB quite easily. Just drag out a `UIScrollView` and position it however you want. Then open the Identity Inspector (cmd+4) and change the class to `CustomView`. You can then hook this to an outlet like normal.

Comment: So would I need to create an instance of this class in my view controller and then alloc and init in say the viewDidLoad method?

Comment: You would treat this like any other IB outlet. So, add the ivar to your controller, add the @property with the `IBOutlet` modifier, @synthesize it, release it in `viewDidUnload` and `dealloc`, and finally connect the outlet in IB. Then by the time the `viewDidLoad` method fires in your controller an instance of this class would have been fully instantiated and added to the controller's view. All of that happens in the background, no need for your to alloc-init it yourself.

Comment: I've done exactly that but it seems to not be loading my view into the scroll view

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want a UIScrollView inside your UIScrollView?

Your scrollView instance should be nil in your init method, so accessing it won't work as expected.

I am not sure the whole construct / hierarchy is what you want...

Comment: well honestly i'm trying to create a custom control that uses a UIScrollView to slide from left to right and believe me it works quite well. The only thing is that i'd like to create a custom class for my control in order for me to be able to connect it in interface builder in a very and have the specifics performed in hiding

Comment: Then you probably should *either* inherit from UIScrollView *or* inherit from a regular UIView and contain one, but not both.