# How can I detect the touch event in the UIScrollView?

Tags: cocoa-touch

In my program, I want the image in the scroll view can be detected when there is a touch. I had read the internet that there are some codes that can help to solve the problem
In a subclass .h file:

```
@interface AllScrollView : UIScrollView 
{
}

@end
```

In the subclass .m file:

```
#import "AllScrollView.h"

@implementation AllScrollView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
  return [super initWithFrame:frame];
}

- (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event 
{   
  if (!self.dragging) 
    [self.nextResponder touchesEnded: touches withEvent:event]; 
  else
    [super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];
}

@end
```

and then I change the method `- (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event` on the main class. However, there is nothing happened and I cannot detect the touch. Do I miss something ? Could anyone give a more detail solution ? Thank you so much!

Comment: Scrollviews automatically detect and handle touch events: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206492/how-to-set-up-a-subclass-of-uiscrollview-and-connect-it-in-interface-builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [Gesture Recognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html) with a scroll view, and they work fine. In your case, I would select a single tap recognizer, like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
singleFingerDTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];


- (IBAction)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Single tap detected");
}
```

Comment: hi, since I am the beginner of xcode, could you give me more information about the above codes? Where should I put this code? Could the IBAction be linked to the image in the .xib file. Thank you so much

Comment: @PeterLam First snippet that sets up the recognizer goes into the designated initializer of your view (typically, it is the `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` method). The method goes into the implementation of your view class. Once inside the `handleSingleTap:` method, call `[sender locationInView:self]` to find the point of the tap in your view. You can link to `IBAction` in the interface builder if you would like to make the same action available independently of the gesture recognizer.

Comment: what is the meaning of self.theView ?

Comment: @PeterLam Oops, I copied the code from a place where the recognizer is added from the init method of the view controller. This is another valid choice, by the way: if you do this, move handleSingleTap to the view controller as well. I fixed the answer to say `self` instead of `self.theView`.

Comment: could you give me the link of the whole code ? because I want to see how the program be done ? I want an example to familiarize the use of Gesture Recognizers. Thank you so much

Comment: @PeterLam There is a link to Apple's document in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried the method that you mentioned before and it gets work. However, the tap geesture recognizer can only allow me assigning one image. If my view has 13 images, how can I solve this problem ? Thank you again

Comment: @PeterLam One way is to add recognizer to image's superview, and then find the image overlapping the tap point.

Comment: sorry, is the method that you say related to the program code ? Could you please give the code ?

Comment: It would probably be a lot easier if you updated your question with the code that works for a single image.